# What does *((int*)&f) do in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, binary

I found a way to convert a float to binary in c through this answer: [Convert float to binary in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868444/convert-float-to-binary-in-c#12868463), but I'm not sure what the code used in the answer `*((int*)&f)` actually does to convert the number. What does it do exactly?

Comment: It takes the address (`float *`), casts to `int *`, and dereferences. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule - use `memcpy` instead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It invokes undefined behavior, meaning your program is invalid if it's reachable.

What someone *intended* for it to do is to reinterpret the bits of a `float` as an `int`, assuming `int` is 32-bit and probably also that `float` is IEEE single.

There are two correct ways to do this (`int` replaced with `uint32_t` to remove the first useless assumption):

1. `(union { float f; uint32_t i; }){f}.i`
2. `uint32_t i; memcpy(&i,&f,sizeof i);`

Comment: Side note: the purpose of re-interpreting the bits of a float is generally to access underlying (implementation defined) internal representation of a float, typically sign bit, biased exponent, and significand bits... Sun fdlibm mathematical library use those bits extensively (for double precision).

Comment: @R.. So if I'm understanding 2 correctly, `memcpy` just copies the address of `f` and makes it the address of `i` as well, and since `i` is a `uint32_t` the bits are reinterpreted as that type? If it is, was IEEE-754 built with this application in mind or is this something that was discovered at a later date?